# *** Assertion failure in -[AppDelegate createDatabaseExecutableFile]

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have application and in application delegate i have code for copy the db file into document folder but it's not working i don't know why because it was working before, and giving following error, please take a look and hope you can find something. Thanks

```
// Creates a writable copy of the bundled default database in the application Documents directory.
- (void) createDatabaseExecutableFile {

    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL _successDB;
    BOOL _successConfig;
    NSFileManager* _fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError* _error;
    NSArray* _paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* _documentsDirectory = [_paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* _writableDBPath = [_documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"turfnutritiontool_ver.db"];
    NSString* _writableConfigPath = [_documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Configuration.plist"];

    _successDB = [_fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_writableDBPath];
    _successConfig = [_fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_writableConfigPath];

    if (_successDB && _successConfig) {

        return;
    }

    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"turfnutritiontool_ver.db"];
    NSString *defaultConfigPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Configuration.plist"];

    _successDB = [_fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:_writableDBPath error:&_error];
    _successConfig = [_fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultConfigPath toPath:_writableConfigPath error:&_error];
    if (!_successDB || !_successConfig) {

        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [_error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
  2012-04-02 13:52:01.162 TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1[2379:b903] *** Assertion failure in -[AppDelegate createDatabaseExecutableFile], /Development/TurfNutritionTool_IOS_5.1/TurfNutritionTool/AppDelegate.m:188
    2012-04-02 13:52:01.165 TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1[2379:b903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to create writable database file with message 'The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists'.'
    *** Call stack at first throw:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x0179a5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018ee313 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x01752ef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
        3   Foundation                          0x011fc3bb -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
        4   TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1           0x00003fef -[AppDelegate createDatabaseExecutableFile] + 831
        5   TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1           0x00003486 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 86
        6   UIKit                               0x009f9c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
        7   UIKit                               0x009fbd88 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 439
        8   UIKit                               0x00a06617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
        9   UIKit                               0x009feabf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
        10  UIKit                               0x00a03f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
        11  GraphicsServices                    0x01e21992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
        12  CoreFoundation                      0x0177b944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
        13  CoreFoundation                      0x016dbcf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
        14  CoreFoundation                      0x016d8f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
        15  CoreFoundation                      0x016d8840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
        16  CoreFoundation                      0x016d8761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
        17  UIKit                               0x009fb7d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623
        18  UIKit                               0x00a07c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
        19  TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1           0x00002ddd main + 125
        20  TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1           0x00002d55 start + 53
        21  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
    )
    terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says "file exists".  Isn't that enough of a clue?

From the [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW17) docs:

> If a file with the same name already exists at dstPath, this method aborts the copy attempt and returns an appropriate error.

By the way, you should check the error after each copy, not once at the end because if an error occurs on the first copy, and the second copy, you'll lose the error information from the first copy.